Why does scdensity not work with boundedRight in this code?
I'm trying to get kernal density estimates for values that are bounded [0, 1] (a proportion), and to get value for where specific quantiles occur in that density estimate. The R package scdensity has a function by the same name, which looks like it should do what I want. However, while setting a lower bound works as expected, setting an upper bound does not.
The following code reproduces my problem with a sample dataset.
# Required package
library(scdensity)

# Sample data
x <- c(0.01, 0.3, 0.5, 0.99)

This code chunk demonstrates that the arguments constraint = "boundedLeft" and opts = list(lowerBound = 0) produce the expected result of density estimates of 0 for x < 0.
# Lower bound

dens1 <- scdensity(x, 
                   constraint = c("boundedLeft"),
                   opts = list(lowerBound = 0))
plot(dens1)
#> Warning in regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm):
#> collapsing to unique 'x' values


This chunk demonstrates that constraint = "boundedRight" and opts = list(upperBound = 1) results in non-zero density estimates for x > 0, which seems inconsistent with the what was specified in the arguments.
# Upper bound

dens2 <- scdensity(x, 
                   constraint = c("boundedRight"),
                   opts = list(upperBound = 1))
plot(dens2)


This chunk demonstrates that when both upper and lower bounds are specified, only the lower bound appears to work as expected.
# Lower & upper bounds

dens3 <- scdensity(x, 
                   constraint = c("boundedLeft", "boundedRight"),
                   opts = list(lowerBound = 0, upperBound = 1))
plot(dens3)
#> Warning in regularize.values(x, y, ties, missing(ties), na.rm = na.rm):
#> collapsing to unique 'x' values


Created on 2024-08-19 with reprex v2.1.0

Tried checking if it's your data by increasing the amount and range of values but no consequence. Seems like it should work according to documentation, so could be a bug. The source code for scdensity() is fairly clean and short so it could be useful to take a look to see...might take a look myself later. It could also be an artifact of the plotting...check dens2$extra and the estimated values directly.

scdensity author here.  Thanks for bringing this to my attention!  There is indeed a bug. If you need to fix it for immediate use, here's how to modify the source:  in weightedKDE.R, starting at line 420, the following code appears:
  if ("boundedRight" %in% P$constraints) {
    gR <- P$g[P$g >= P$upperBound]
    if (!symmetric) {
      AshapeNew <- NormalGridFcn(gR, 0, P$y, P$h)
    } else {
      if (P$upperBound < P$PoS) {
        stop("The upper bound cannot be less than the point of symmetry.")
      }
      if ("boundedLeft" %in% P$constraints) {
        if (!isTRUE(all.equal(P$lowerBound + P$upperBound, 2*P$PoS))) {
          stop("Lower and upper bounds must be equidistant from the point of symmetry.")
        }
      } else {
        AshapeNew <- NormalGridFcn(gR, 0, yL, P$h) + NormalGridFcn(gR, 0, yR, P$h)
        P$Ashape <- rbind(P$Ashape, -AshapeNew)   # <-- PROBLEM
        P$bshape <- c(P$bshape, rep(-P$boundTol, dim(AshapeNew)[1]))   # <-- PROBLEM
      }
    }
  # *** PROBLEM lines should go here ***
  }


The two lines marked PROBLEM are in the wrong place; they should be moved down out of the else block. The way it is shown above, the constraints in AshapeNew never get written to the constraint matrix P$Ashape.
The code has a lot of branching logic due to the many possible combinations of constraints; these lines ended up in the wrong place.  Not sure how it escaped my notice during development!
I'll try to get an update through CRAN as soon as I can.
By the way, probably it's already clear to you, but scdensity will only produce estimates that go to zero on both sides, because it's using a Gaussian KDE.  So, if your proportion's true distribution is not negligible near 0 and 1, you will need to try something different.
